# Using a photo as my website's background

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a random picture of a moose lying around so I wanted to use it as my ruby on rails website's background. I fumble online for a bit and here is what I got.

```
html { 
  background-image: url(images/moose.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The above does not work, my background is still white. What am I doing wrong? 
The picture of a moose is located in app/assets/images/moose.jpg

I've tried using html body { } as oppose to html and background as oppose to background-image

Comment: you need to wrap: `images/moose.jpg` in single quotes

Comment: I tried using single quotes and double quotes but it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

```
<html> 

<body style="background-image: url(output.png);">
Hello this is a text line.</body>
</html>
```

I assume your image to be in same directory of your html page. Otherwise give the relative path to image like C:/images/output.png

Comment: Is your browser up-to-date? and please elaborate your folder and files locations of html and jpg.

Comment: Yes both my Chrome and Firefox are up to date. This is a rails project so all of my html (html.erb) are under app/asset/views. My pictures are in app/assets/images

Answer (score 1):

You can't use html, you have to use body. It should be:

```
body {
    background:url('images/moose.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Open chrome inspector and look at what background-image styles are loading.

Comment: interesting, I listened to you and inspected the page. It appears that the background-image property that entire line has been crossed out, with a yellow exclamation mark next to it. When I hover my mouse over it says invalid property value

Comment: @user3277633 sorry, all the properties listed after the url aren't valid properties for a `background-url` attribute (only the url is), but they are when you do just `background:` which accepts all the possible properties for a background

Answer (score 0):

url function requires a string, you need to use single quotes to pass in the string file you are trying to load.

```
background-image:url('images/moose.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Here is what the def of URL says on w3schools.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: hmm unfortunately it does not work. Is it something to do with rails rather than CSS?